# preg_replace function to append a string to all the hyperlinks of a page

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i want to append my own value to all hyperlinks in a page... e.g if there are links:

```
<a href="abc.htm?val=1">abc 1</a> <br/>
<a href="abc.htm?val=2">abc 1</a> <br/>
<a href="abc.htm?val=3">abc 1</a> <br/>
<a href="abc.htm?val=4">abc 1</a> <br/>
```

I want to add next var like "type=int" to all hyperlinks

output should be:

```
<a href="abc.htm?val=1&type=int">abc 1</a> <br/>
<a href="abc.htm?val=2&type=int">abc 1</a> <br/>
<a href="abc.htm?val=3&type=int">abc 1</a> <br/>
<a href="abc.htm?val=4&type=int">abc 1</a> <br/>
```

I hope it can be done quite easily with preg_replace function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a matter of just appending the variable to the `href` attribute, then this would work:

```
#                                              v-- &amp; instead of & for W3C validation
preg_replace('/(<a\\s+[^>]+href="[^"]*)(")/', '${1}&amp;type=int$2', $page_src);
```

But if you are wanting code-hardiness, in that `href="index.php"` gets changed into `href="index.php?type=int"` and not `href="index.php&type=int"`, then you'll need some extra checking:

```
function process_link_matches ($matches) {
    # get rid of full matching string; all parts are already covered
    array_shift($matches);

    if (preg_match('/\\?[^"]/', $matches[2])) {
        # link already contains $_GET parameters
        $matches[1] .= '&type=int';
    } else {
        # starting a new list of parameters
        $matches[1] .= '?type=int';
    }

    return implode($matches);
}

$page_src = preg_replace_callback('/(<a\\s+[^>]+href=")([^"]*)("[^>]*>)/', 
    'process_link_matches', $page_src);
```

Comment: Simple solution was like but u pointed a possible hazard or index.php&type=int... that's gr8

simple soln:
preg_replace('/href=\'([^\']*)\'/', 'href=\'${1}&type=int\'', $page_src);

Comment: @KoolKabin this would append your string to all src attributes, including <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"> for exemple

Comment: This rocks ! However i had to replace
`'/(<a\s+[^>]+href=")([^"]*)("[^>]*>)/'`
with
`'/(<a\s+[^>]*href=")([^"]*)("[^>]*>)/'`
(The first "+" becomes "*")

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [output buffer](http://php.net/outcontrol) and [`output_add_rewrite_var`](http://php.net/output_add_rewrite_var) to do that. You might need to adjust [*url_rewriter.tags*](http://php.net/url_rewriter.tags) to only rewrite the `href` attributes of `a` elements.

Comment: Surely that would affect more than just hyperlinks.

Comment: @salathe: You can adjust the list of tags with *url\_rewriter.tags*.

Comment: Nice of you to mention that in your answer. ;)  @KoolKabin: the default tags affected by Gumbo's answer are more wide-ranging than hrefs attributes on hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
preg_replace('/(\<a [^>]*href=")([^"]*)"/i', '&\1\2type=int"', page);
```

Be warned, though, that this is likely to break on arbitrary html files. I'd recommend using Regex for HTML manipulation only as a one shot operation. If you need to do this more often, or on a lot of files, consider using a HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not a regexp-expert, but this sounds like you should think of using sessions or cookies...